# Why does the Touchpad of Acer Aspire V3-551G not work on Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad, acer

I've just bought a new PC which is Acer Aspire V3-551G. First of all, I installed Ubuntu 12.10. However, I couldn't use some features because it's not stable.

Then, I installed 12.04. But my touchpad doesn't work. I found `kde-config-touchad` and `kcm-touchpad` from the repos. Even so, it still doesn't work.

By the way, my touchpad's buttons work and my OS is 64bit.

Comment: I solved this problem installing **xserver-xorg-input-synaptics** package. Thank you all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP said:

I solved this problem installing the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package.