# Touchpad of Acer Aspire E5-551G not detected on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, acer, aspire

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my Acer Aspire E5 but the touchpad doesn't work. This is the result of xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳                                           id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

(the third should be the touchpad).

This is from my /proc/bus/input/devices file:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=06cb Product=2970 Version=0111
N: Name="   "
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:13.0-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event13 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
```

If I press Fn+F7 nothing happens (though if I press any other Fn+F* it works correctly).

I already followed instructions on these links but still doesn't work:

[Why does the Touchpad of Acer Aspire V3-551G not work on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259406/why-does-the-touchpad-of-acer-aspire-v3-551g-not-work-on-ubuntu)
[touchpad is not detected in ubuntu 14.04 on acer aspire one AO756](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506552/touchpad-is-not-detected-in-ubuntu-14-04-on-acer-aspire-one-ao756)
[Ubuntu 13.04: Problem with the Synaptics touchpad on a Acer Aspire One ZG5 (AOA110) not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325592/ubuntu-13-04-problem-with-the-synaptics-touchpad-on-a-acer-aspire-one-zg5-aoa1) (can't find Synaptiks on software center!)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...after a year and a half, new version (16.04) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest was to update to 14.10 but the right click is missing. Or if you are more advanced user update the kernel to 3.17-4*. The device is still Unknown.